# Nginx server not able to find matching location for a request

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I am having hard time figuring out the right regex for my location to match any request which follow the pattern as below.

```
/outputresources/blahbalh/blahblahhhhh/file.gkg
/outputresources/blah8888/file
/outputresources/b;aaaaahhh/blah/blaaaahhhhh/file
```

also i want to capture any value that comes after /outputresource/ so i can get in in my lua script.

Have tried regex

```
~ /outputResources/(?<file>(.*)*)
~ /outputResources/(?<file>(.*/*)*)
```

I am using openresty nginx

Comment: It is `~ ^/outputresources/(?<file>.*)` (or `~* ^/outputresources/(?<file>.*)` if you want case-insensitive matching).

Comment: @Ivan I tried that but then nginx match the location if i the request is /outputresources/somefile.blah .. But fails to find match when /outputresources/blah/somefile.blah

Comment: Nginx will look at all the `location` statements before choosing one to process the request. Even if the regular expression matches the URI, Nginx may choose a different location. See [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Comment: That regex matches any of request examples you provided. If it doesn't work for you, some other location block take precedence over it. You need to show your full server config, at least all location blocks.

Comment: IvanShatsky Richard Smith Thanks for that call out. I guess thats what happens in my case. For some reason some other location takes precedence over the actual one. Will need to add more specific regex around my location :)